# Redirecting requests to a PHP application to a text file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect all requests to my site to a .txt file so I found two ways of doing it,

**Way 1:**

Redirecting to a php file which would display the .txt file contents like below.

**.htaccess**

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html?$
RewriteRule \.html?$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');

header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="details.txt"');

readfile('details.txt');
?>
```

**Way 2:**

Using .htaccess to redirect to the .txt file directly

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex details.txt index.php
```

So both give me the same result, is there any other difference that I am missing. Which way is the best way? I need immediate help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for Way2 '.htaccess to redirect to the .txt file directly'

It will be faster and efficient because there is no need of PHP Parsing. In second method the PHP handler should parse the script , open text file and display it. So definitely Way2 is better.

Comment: Ok you are saying that both ways are the same but Way2 is faster, am I right?. I am not worried about the server load or anything, its just an assignment so I want to know whether both are the same.

Answer (score 2):

In Way 1: you can execute any command using php then go to txt file. It will call php engine too.

In Way 2: It will call txt file directly. So it will save your server load. But you  cannot execute any command.

As Way 1 will pass through two engine so it will be slow but you can use it as you like. On the other hand Way 2 will be faster but sourceless.

So which way you will prefer it will depend on your project.